# Is there a non-VBA way to calculate the average of the sum of two sets of columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating an excel spreadsheet to track when an item is received as well as when a response to the item having been received has been made (ie: my mail was delivered at 1:00pm (item received) but I didn't check the mail until 5:00pm (response to item having been received)).

I need to track both the date and time of the item being received and want to separate these in two separate columns.  At the moment this translates to:

```
Column A: Date item received
Column B: Time item received
Column L: Date item was responded to having been received
Column M: Time item was responded to having been received
```

In essence I'm looking to run calculations on the response time between when the item is received and when it has been responded to (ie: average response time, number of responses in less than an hour, and even things like the number of responses that took between 2 and 3 hours where Bob was the person who responded).

The per-line pseudo code would look something like:

```
(Lr + Mr) - (Ar + Br) ' where L,M,A,B are the columns and 'r' is the row number.
```

An example, with the following data:

```
1. A               B                 L                  M
2. 1/5/19     10:00          1/5/19         12:00
3. 1/5/19      21:00         1/6/19         1:00
4. 1/5/19      22:00         1/5/19         23:00
5. 1/6/19      3:00           1/6/19         4:00
```

The outcome for the average response time would be 2 hours (average(rows 2-5) = average(2, 4, 1, 1) = 2)

The number of items with an average response times would be as follows:

```
(<=1 hour) = 2
(>1 & <=2) = 2
(>2 & <=3) = 0
(>3) = 1
```

I don't know (or can find) a function that will perform this and then let me use it within something like a countifs() or averageifs() function.

While I could do this (fairly easily) in VBA, the practical implementation of this spreadsheet limits me to standard Excel.  I suspect that sumproduct() will be fundamental to make this work, but I feel that I need something like a sumsum() function (which doesn't exist) and I'm not familiar with sumproduct() to better understand what to even look for to set something like this up.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid putting in a working column with the formula you specified?

Comment: What could help is some sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: @Michael I am. I did think it would simplify things (coding wise) to use a second column, but in practice would be a little tricky. I was hoping for an in line solution, if possible.

Comment: @JvdV I added some sample data and outcomes above.

Comment: @Jon Can you explain why the average wouldn't be `4,4,1,1`? Or is that a typo?

Comment: @JvdV whoops, that was supposed to be a 2 hour difference in that row. My bad. It's been corrected.

Comment: @Jon, on that same note `(>1 & <=2) = 2` should be 1? Either way, I added an answer below.

Comment: @JvdV I'm not sure what you mean.  There are two rows with a difference of two hours (or am I doing the math wrong here - I have been rather tired...).

Comment: Only one row larger than one and Equal or smaller than two ;)

Comment: @JvdV Oh good grief, yes.  You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not so familiar with `SUMPRODUCT()` or the likes I would suggest one helper column. Like so:

[image]

You can see the formula used is:

```
=((C2+D2)-(A2+B2))
```

You can probably do all type of calculations on this helper column. Note, column is formatted `hh:mm`. However, if you want to look into `SUMPRODUCT()` you could think about these:

[image]

Formula in `H2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ROUND((((A2:A5+B2:B5)-(C2:C5+D2:D5))*-24),2)<=1))
```

Formula in `H3`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROUND((((A2:A5+B2:B5)-(C2:C5+D2:D5))*-24),2)>1)*(ROUND((((A2:A5+B2:B5)-(C2:C5+D2:D5))*-24),2)<=2))
```

Formula in `H4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROUND((((A2:A5+B2:B5)-(C2:C5+D2:D5))*-24),2)>2)*(ROUND((((A2:A5+B2:B5)-(C2:C5+D2:D5))*-24),2)<3))
```

Formula in `H5`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ROUND((((A2:A5+B2:B5)-(C2:C5+D2:D5))*-24),2)>3))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is along the lines of what I expected to have to do.  I want to test with some of my actual numbers (and some hand calculations for accuracy), but I think this is what I originally had in mind.  I really appreciate all the assistance! (@Michael as well!)

Answer (score 0):

The helper column is the easiest approach. It gives you the time differences that you can then easily analyse however you want. Analysis without the helper column is possible, but the approach differs depending on what type of analysis you want to do.

For the example you provided, which is counting the number of time differences grouped into ranges, you would use the FREQUENCY function:

```
=FREQUENCY(C2:C5+D2:D5-A2:A5-B2:B5,F2:F4)
```

In F2:F4 (called the "bins"), enter the upper limit of each range you want to count. The Frequency function counts up to and including the first value, then counts from there up to and including the second value, and so on. Enter the bins as times, e.g. 1:00 for 1 hour.

Note that Frequency is an array-entered *and* an array-returning function. This you means you need to first select the range that will contain all output values, G2:G5 in this example, then enter the function, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Also note that Frequency returns an array that is one element larger than the number of bins specified. The extra element is the count of all values greater than the largest bin specified.

[image: Img]

Comment: I hadn't thought of frequency... Interesting...  Let me play with this a bit and get back to you.  Thanks for the direction.

Comment: I really appreciate your input on this.  I'm looking for a non array-based solution primarily because what I'm looking to implement will be used by others who will not be familiar with this, but this is great to know.  Thanks so much!